# Problem with sets

Tags: linear-algebra

We say that a set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$ with at least three elements is free of arithmetic progress if for any $a, b, c \in A$ distinct, we have $a + b\neq 2c$. Show that the set {0,1,2,...,6560} contains a subset A with at least 256 elements, free of arithmetic progress.

Comment: Can you help me, please, with any idea?

Comment: What have you tried?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach**

**Hint:** Given a set $A$ that is AP-free, there is a natural way to create a set of size $2|A|$ that is AP free.
Do this till the set has size 256.
If you're lucky (and this is possible), the largest number (starting from 0) will be 6560.

---

**Second approach** (Technically the same as the first)

**Hint:** $6560+1 = 3^8$